# How to close Inventory with name in task

Tags: java, bukkit

I am looking for a method to close Inventory in a task, no events etc., I would just like to close Inventory which I will show, is it possible?

```
public static void stopEventSystem() {
    int stop = cfg.getConfig().getInt("event.stop")*1200;
    Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bukkit.broadcastMessage("§7Event stop");
            status = false;
            for(Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                //???
            }
        }
    }, stop);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at`player.closeInventory()`. You can also use `player.getOpenInventory()` to get current open inventory, so you can check name etc. If player does not have any inventory open this will return that smaller crafting grid according to documentation.

For more methods that interact with Player, you should check the documentation:
https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html